# I can't turn on wifi on fujitsu sh530

Tags: wireless, networking

I had a problem with my wifi on fujitsu sh530 laptop, 
here is some info

```
maxwell@maxwell-LIFEBOOK-SH530:~$ rfkill list wlan
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

as you can see is either my wireless lan driver install wrongly or soft block is blocking
I try to go `System setting -> network -> wireless -> click turn on` but it fail to turn on it will just go back to off after you click on.

If I use additional driver in the system settings, it won't able to locate my wifi

Do you had any info I should I reinstall my wireless lan driver correctly?

thank you

Best Regards,
maxwell

Comment: How about `rfkill unblock all`? Have you tried that? If that doesn't resolve the issue, please edit your question and include result of `lspci`, `sudo lshw -c network`

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, the module *acer-wmi* doesn't correctly translate key presses to action; that is,turn on the wireless. Try removing it:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

If this works, blacklist *acer-wmi*:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
gedit /etc/rc.local
```

The text editor gedit will open the rc.local file. Right above *exit 0* add a new line:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Now exit your sudo session:

```
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if it's working as expected.